# Angular JS safari (MAC OSX) Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Recently I added a [facebook login](https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook) function to my angular JS web project . On localhost everything worked like a charm (on all browsers). After uploading it an error occurred but only on Safari (Mac OS X). Chrome, Firefox and iOS Safari works as intended.

```
    Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=f...
http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:421
http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:38:100
n@http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:326
g@http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:37:181
http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:37:350
n@http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:326
g@http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:37:181
eb@http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:40:436
d@http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:19:383
yc@http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:20:180
Zd@http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:19:2
http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:292:53
fire@http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3148:35
fireWith@http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3260:11
ready@http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3472:24
completed@http://myApp.myDomain.com/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3503:15
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Apparently only Safari had issues with the url path loading the Facebook login JS file from the bower directory. After changing the path it worked. I do not know why every other browser was getting the path correctly while Safari had issues, so  the root cause is still not clear.